# Update with LIKE

Tags: mysql

```
UPDATE jos_ezrealty

  SET jos_ezrealty.locid = p.id

,jos_ezrealty.locality = p.locality

,jos_ezrealty.owncoords = 1

FROM poblacion p

  WHERE jos_ezrealty.alias LIKE '%' || p.locality || '%'
```

---

It gives me:

`#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM poblacion p WHERE jos_ezrealty.alias LIKE '%' || p.locality || '%'' at line 5`

Comment: Why do you want the WHERE clause? It will update all rows anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be like:

```
UPDATE jos_ezrealty join poblacion 

SET jos_ezrealty.locid = p.id

,jos_ezrealty.locality = p.locality

,jos_ezrealty.owncoords = 1

WHERE jos_ezrealty.alias LIKE CONCAT('%', p.locality, '%');
```

Comment: maybe `LIKE CONCAT('%', p.locality, '%')`. `||` is the SQL concatenation operator.

Comment: Thanks. didn't knew that ... not regular to MYSQL. Though that's just an char he want.

Answer (score 2):

Read on the [`UPDATE` syntax for MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/update.html).

```
UPDATE jos_ezrealty AS e
  JOIN poblacion p
    ON e.alias LIKE '%' || p.locality || '%'
SET e.locid = p.id
  , e.locality = p.locality
  , e.owncoords = 1 ;
```

Comment: This gave me the same locality and locid in jos_ezrealty from the first row of poblacion